# I would like to delete data in cells if the date in another corresponding cell is before today

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with dates in ascending order in column "A". Columns "B" & "C" have data that is entered in by users. If the corresponding date in column "A" is before today's date I would like to have the data entered into cells "B" & "C" deleted. I am really not sure how to do this.

Data as is:

[image]

Desired result (assuming today is 5/1/2017):

[image]

Comment: Loop through column A, if the date is less than the inputed date clearcontents on B and C in that row.  When the date is reach exit the loop.  Or use Application.Worksheetunction.Match to find the row that the date is in and set B1:C and that row to clearcontents.

Comment: Any chance you could help with the code to do that? I've never really worked with VBA.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub removedate()
Dim rw As Long
With ActiveSheet
    rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(Date), .Range("A:A").Value2, 0) - 1
    .Range("B1:C" & rw).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

---

If your dates are not continuous and there is a chance that the date may not exist then use this code instead:

```
Sub removedate()
Dim rw As Long
With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(Date), .Range("A:A").Value2, 0) - 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rw = 0 Then
       rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(Date), .Range("A:A").Value2, 1)
    End If
    .Range("B1:C" & rw).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. But the problem with this approach would be if the today's date is not found in column A, the code will throw an error. To handle that you can declare rw as variant and use rw = application.match instead and test if not iserror(rw). Just a thought.

Comment: That approach uses late binding I prefer to use on error goto next and do a test for the error.  But as per the OP's data example the days are continuous. @sktneer

Comment: I agree with you here. :)

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I'm thinking about using a named range for "B1:C". Let's say I named the range "Data". How would I go about changing what you've provided?

Comment: When you say `named range` are you talking a variable range in vba, or a workbook/worksheet named range, the first is possible the second is not as it needs to be variable.  The first would be something like `Set rng = .Range("B1:C" & rw)`  Then you can use `rng.ClearContents`.  Make sure you declare `rng`: `Dim rng as Range` @Djones12

Comment: @Djones12 as to the second you would need to use a formula to be dynamic based on the date and make it a workbook named range.  Then you would call it thus: `ThisWorkbook.Range("YourRangeName").ClearContents`.  How to make a variable workbook named range is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try something like this...

```
Sub ClearData()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D1:D" & lr).Formula = "=IF(A1<Today(),Na(),"""")"
On Error Resume Next
Range("D1:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
Range("D1:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Offset(0, -2).ClearContents
Columns(4).Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub clearData()
Dim lastRow as Long
Dim varArray() as Variant
Dim rng as Range
Dim i as Long
Dim mySheet as Worksheet

Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nameOfYourSheet")
lastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = mySheet.Range("A1:C" & CStr(lastRow))
varArray = rng


For i = 1 to rng.rows.count

   If varArray(i, 1) <> Date Then
       varArray(i, 2) = vba.vbnullString
       varArray(i, 3) = vba.vbNullString
   End if

Next i

rng = varArray
End Sub
```

Untested, but something like this could work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one row for each date, and that the dates are sequential, and that the first row is not today's date:

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells((Date - .Cells(1, 1).Value), "C")).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```